# How to break this text so it doesn't overflow? - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a widget that builds a list from an array. Each item in the array builds a widget with some columns and rows. I want the text to break so It doesnt overflow.
I've tried adding `overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis` to the Text or wrapping the Row that wraps the icon and the text that overflow with a Expanded widget, but both didn't work.

Actually it looks like this:
[image]

This is my code:

```dart
child: Column(
    verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
    textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    children: < Widget > [
        Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: < Widget > [
                Row(
                    children: [
                        const Icon(Icons.medication),
                            //
                            // This is the text that overflows
                            //
                            Text(
                                entries[index].pillname,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 25,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                            ),
                    ],
                ),
                Text(
                    entries[index].pillTimeStr,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 28,
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 79, 79, 79),
                    ),
                ),
            ],
        ),
        Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: < Widget > [
                Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                        child: FloatingActionButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                    entries[index].pilldone = !entries[index].pillDone;
                                });
                            },
                            tooltip:
                            entries[index].pillDone ? 'Tomada' : 'No tomada',
                            backgroundColor: entries[index].pillDone ?
                            Colors.green :
                            Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                            child: const Icon(Icons.check),
                        ),
                ),
                Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                        child: FloatingActionButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                                showAdaptiveActionSheet(
                                    context: context,
                                    cancelAction: CancelAction(
                                        title: const Text('Cancelar'),
                                    ),
                                    actions: < BottomSheetAction > [
                                        BottomSheetAction(
                                            title: const Text('Modificar'),
                                                onPressed: () {}),
                                        BottomSheetAction(
                                            title: const Text('Eliminar'),
                                                onPressed: () {
                                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                                    _askRemovePill(entries[index].iD);
                                                }),
                                    ]);
                            },
                            tooltip: 'Eliminar',
                            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                            child: const Icon(Icons.mode_edit),
                        )),
            ],
        ),
    ],
),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, all you need to do is wrap your Text inside the Row with an Expanded widget

```
Expanded(
    child: Text(/*......your text widget........*/),
),
```

The Expanded widget gives your Text widget horizontal constraints

IF you don't wish to see the text go on to the next line,
use the overflow property on the text

> *overflow : TextOverflow.ellipsis, //inside Text*

Comment: This worked! Seems what I was doing is wrong (using expanded instead of row). Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Wrap widget instead of the Row widget. It will break the text to the next line should there be an overflow.
Like this,

```
         Wrap(
                children: [
                    const Icon(Icons.medication),
                        //
                        // This is the text that overflows
                        //
                        Text(
                            entries[index].pillname,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 25,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                        ),
                ],
            ),
            Text(
                entries[index].pillTimeStr,
                style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 28,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 79, 79, 79),
                ),
            ),
        ],
    ),
```

Comment: Your answer helped me to see a different way, but this made my icon and text be separated. Tanks anyway :)